# UILabel in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I designed `UICollectionViewCell` in storyboard .Consists 2 elements UILabel, UIImageView.

for UILabel i given constrains leading=0, trailing=0, bottom=0, height=100

My **collectionViewCell**
[image]

But when i run in simulator:
[image]

Edit: when i observed in interface inspector, label is not attached to view on collectionView:
[image]

Comment: are you sure that this all constraints are enabled? Also check that you have provided it only for specific size classes

Comment: @MehulThakkar : i am working for iPad . so i given  wR hR

Comment: @MehulThakkar: see my Edit

Comment: @Uday.M you are giving constraints to `uicollectionviewcell` or `uicollectionview`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved issue by adding these lines in cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
[cell setNeedsLayout];
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
```